# The image uploaded to s3 have the same image name but different picture i see when i open the image

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am taking picture from my android phone and uploading to the s3 ,image is getting successfully uploaded ,i can also see the same image name in s3 but the picture inside the image is different from the one i was uploaded it showing the old picture with new image name.

Code:

```
protected void takePicture() {
        if (null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+name+"_"+dl+".jpg");
            final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                        mBitmapToSave1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        mBitmapToSave = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmapToSave, width, height, true);
                        int w = scaled.getWidth();
                        int h = scaled.getHeight();
                        // Setting post rotate to 90
                        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                        mtx.postRotate(-180);
                        // Rotating Bitmap
                        mBitmapToSave = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
                        // mBitmapToSave = Bitmap.createBitmap(width+rowPadding/pixelStride,height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                        // mBitmapToSave.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

                        if (detector.isOperational() && mBitmapToSave != null) {
                            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(mBitmapToSave).build();
                            SparseArray<Face> faces = detector.detect(frame);

                            for (index = 0; index < faces.size(); ++index) {
                                Face face = faces.valueAt(index);
                            }
                            if (faces.size() == 0) {
                                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.not);
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                //Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera2API.this, "Face Not detected Adjust Camera Properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                    c++;
                                    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera2API.this, "Face Found " + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera2API.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    setFileToUpload();
                                    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera2API.this, "" +c, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                               // Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera2API.this, "completed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
```

The setFileToUpload method:

```
public void setFileToUpload(){


 TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(

                "train-faces/TrainingData"+"/"+name,     /* The bucket to upload to */
                name+"_"+dl+".jpg",    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                fileToUpload       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );

        transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
    }
```

Comment: Let's see the code

Comment: @MadsJustesen i have added the code.